# Problems with control flow with subroutines and functions

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having issues with trying to get a function to return back to the `if` statement that called it. Whether I use `return` or `exit`, it completely ignores the statement and proceeds with the rest of the script, even when it's commented out.

I want this to work pretty simply, a couple `if` statements, a list of functions, and a reload of the script. Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
#NoEnv

SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
^!r::Reload

global
ifNotExist timeclock.ini
    FileAppend,, timeclock.ini

IniRead, 4_Days, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 4_Days, 0
IniRead, 5_Days, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 5_Days, 0
IniRead, In, timeclock.ini, MAIN, In, 0
IniRead, Out, timeclock.ini, MAIN, Out, 0
IniRead, DSP, timeclock.ini, MAIN, DSP, 0


!\::
Gui, Show, W280 H150 Center, Schedule
    Gui, Add, Radio, Checked%4_Days% v4_Days, 4 Days
    Gui, Add, Radio, Checked%5_Days% v5_Days, 5 Days
    Gui, Add, Button, y+40 gCancel, Cancel

    Gui, Add, Text, ym, Time in:
    Gui, Add, Edit, w50 Number vIn, %In%
    Gui, Add, Text,, Time out:
    Gui, Add, Edit, w50 Number vOut, %Out%


    Gui, Add, Button, Default gContinue, OK
    return

    Cancel:
    {
    Gui, Destroy
    return
    }

    Continue:
    {
    Gui, Submit

    }

    DSPA:=0
    DSPB:=0

    if (In = 2130) {
    DSPA:=2
    DSPB:=8
    DSP=10
    }

    if (In = 2300) {
    DSPA:=0.5
    DSPB:=7.5
    DSP=8
    }


    IniWrite, %4_Days%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 4_Days
    IniWrite, %5_Days%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 5_Days
    IniWrite, %In%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, In
    IniWrite, %Out%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, Out
    IniWrite, %DSP%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, DSP


    If (4_Days = 1) {
        sub_DSP(DSPA)
        reload
    }   
        sub_DSP(x)
        {
        send {tab 4}
        loop, 5 {
            send D
            sleep 1000
            }
        send {tab}
        sleep 250
        send x
        sleep 300
        loop, 8 {
            send +{tab}
            sleep 300
        }
        sleep 300
        send {enter}
        sleep 300
        send {tab 2}
        sleep 300
        return
        }


/*  

        send %in%
        sleep 300
        send {tab 3}
        sleep 300
        send 2330
        sleep 300
        Loop, 32 {
            send {tab}
            sleep 100
        }



        middleDay:
        send {tab 4}
        loop, 5 {
            send D
            sleep 1000
            }
        send {tab}
```

*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, all instructionis *after* any `return` keyword will not be executed. `^!r::Reload` is the short form for

```
^!r::
reload
return
```

and therefore, the inireads will **never** be executed.

Secondly, you are executing the `gui, add, ...` commands more than once. You might want to put them only into the auto-execution block (*before* the hotkeys / labels) and only include the `Gui, Show, ...` in your `!\::` hotkey. Then, if you use `Gui, Hide` instead of `Gui, Destroy`, the gui will not be gone completely, and any change to the elements you made will not be lost after a reopening (in the same session), even without iniwrites.

Thirdly, you don't need the `{}` as you use them in the beginning of your `Cancel` or `Continue` label: ONLY use them in functions!! (or if-statements, loops, whatever)

Fourthly, you forgot to enclose the `Continue` label with a `return`. This can and probably will lead to severe errors.

Fifhly, you don't need to use the keyword `global`outside a function necessarily. You only defined one function called `sub_DSP`, and in it, you don't access any of your global variables like `4_Days`.

Your function `sub_DSP(x) {}` looks nice to me, except you *don't* need the `return` keyword within a function, except if you want to return a value (e.g. `return x`, so you could call it this way: `myVar := sub_DSP("hi")`) or terminate earlier on.

Your new code might look something like this: (but I advice you to revamp your code yourself manually)

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

ifNotExist timeclock.ini
    FileAppend,, timeclock.ini

IniRead, 4_Days, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 4_Days, 0
IniRead, 5_Days, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 5_Days, 0
IniRead, In, timeclock.ini, MAIN, In, 0
IniRead, Out, timeclock.ini, MAIN, Out, 0
IniRead, DSP, timeclock.ini, MAIN, DSP, 0

Gui, Add, Radio, Checked%4_Days% v4_Days, 4 Days
Gui, Add, Radio, Checked%5_Days% v5_Days, 5 Days
Gui, Add, Button, y+40 gCancel, Cancel
Gui, Add, Text, ym, Time in:
Gui, Add, Edit, w50 Number vIn, %In%
Gui, Add, Text,, Time out:
Gui, Add, Edit, w50 Number vOut, %Out%
Gui, Add, Button, Default gContinue, OK

return

^!r::Reload

!\::
    Gui, Show, W280 H150 Center, Schedule
return

Cancel:
GuiClose:   ; standard behaviour of GuiClose is: gui, destroy
    Gui, Hide
return

Continue:
    Gui, Submit
    DSPA:=0
    DSPB:=0
    if (In = 2130) {
        DSPA:=2
        DSPB:=8
        DSP=10
    }
    if (In = 2300) {
        DSPA:=0.5
        DSPB:=7.5
        DSP=8
    }

    IniWrite, %4_Days%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 4_Days
    IniWrite, %5_Days%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, 5_Days
    IniWrite, %In%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, In
    IniWrite, %Out%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, Out
    IniWrite, %DSP%, timeclock.ini, MAIN, DSP

    If (4_Days = 1) {
            sub_DSP(DSPA)
            reload
        }
return  

sub_DSP(x)
{
    send {tab 4}
    loop, 5 {
        send D
        sleep 1000
    }
    send {tab}
    sleep 250
    send x
    sleep 300
    loop, 8 {
        send +{tab}
        sleep 300
    }
    sleep 300
    send {enter}
    sleep 300
    send {tab 2}
    sleep 300
}


/*  

        send %in%
        sleep 300
        send {tab 3}
        sleep 300
        send 2330
        sleep 300
        Loop, 32 {
            send {tab}
            sleep 100
        }



        middleDay:
        send {tab 4}
        loop, 5 {
            send D
            sleep 1000
            }
        send {tab}

*/
```

Comment: That's weird, the `Iniread` function is one of the few things that has been working for me! I can actually just take that out at this point, I had it there super early for debugging.

Thanks for the heads-up on the Gui. Your way is strictly better. I hadn't ever written anything in AHK, and some changes to the interface I wrote this for required a rewrite, and I was trying to class up my 700+ lines of repetitive commands. 

I'll bet the missing `Return` was the entire dang reason I accepted my fate of needing to reload the entire script after each run.

Comment: (sorry for wall of text above, I can't edit it to add line breaks now.)<br/></br>

Good point on global, that was an artifact from a previous flow I was trying to use, where I was going to do things less flexibly with `Gosub`.<br/><br/>

There'll be a few more functions later, but I wanted to make sure I could get it working with one. You've been a big help and I'll try this out again next time I get to work. (our time-clock entry is a nightmare). <br/><br/>

One last question for ya - any idea why the commented-out code wasn't getting ignored?

Comment: Okay, I see. I'm not sure about the iniread stuff - afaik, it should not have worked before. - Commented-out code can never execute, that's impossible. I guess, you were using some more `/* */` further down below or further up above? They might have conflicted with each other.. weird. Be sure to tell if everything went right!

Comment: Hay! That really helped. I was able to get the rest of the script built and the other subroutines work correctly as well. It all really hinged on missing that `return`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Since you're new here, please don't forget to always mark the answer **accepted** which helped most in solving the problem, otherwise ppl will see your question as unanswered. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)